# How do I nest one form-wizard inside another?

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I am implementing a `web-app`, using Django v1.9. I need deployment and configuration of the site to be as foolproof as possible.

So I want to implement a First Use scenario, which allows the site admin to configure the site via the site itself.

The obvious candidate for this is a Form Wizard.

The site needs a couple of resources configured. It can have multiple instances of each resources, but must have *at least one* instance of each.

Thus, a minimal first use sequence might be:

1. Configure an instance of ResourceA
2. Configure an instance of ResourceB
3. Make these the active instances.
4. Do other one-off setup

Later on, the admin needs to define other instances for these resources and steps 1 and 2 above are complex enough to each warrant their own `FormWizard`; especially as they need to be used independently to configure additional instances of each resource type.

This means my first use scenario is actually

- Start First Use Wizard

  - Run 'Add a Resource 1 Instance' wizard
  - Run 'Add a resource 2 Instance' wizard
  - Do other one-off stuff on a few more forms
- End First Use Wizard

My heart tells me I ought to be able nest wizards in this way, gaining good re-use of functionality. Django, and Python in general, are all about DRY.

But I'm stumped trying to work out how. I've been googling and experimenting for enough time to feel there's nothing out there on this.

**Can this be done? If so, how?**

EDIT:

To try and clarify. Suppose each Wizard had a Function based View associated with it

```
def AddResource1view(request):
    # Display the pages of the wizard to build object 1
    # for model Resource1
    object1.save()
    return object1

def AddResource2view(request):
    # Display the pages of the wizard to build object 2
    # for model Resource2
    object2.save()
    return object2

def FirstUseView(request):
    config = SystemConfiguration()
    config.r1 = AddResource1view(request)
    config.r2 = AddResource2view(request)
    # NOw step through the remaining pages of FirstUse wizard
    # filling out config
    ...
    config.save()
```

My `urls.py` would have URLs that point to each of the three Views (via `FormWizard.as_view()`) So you could run either of the Resource wizards independently, or as part of the outer FirstUse wizard.

Obviously, the above is not real code - it just gives the idea of what I mean by nesting.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your problem but did you have a look at this http://yergler.net/blog/2013/09/03/nested-formsets-redux/?

Comment: No, it's not a formset I'm after. I was trying to create a workflow where one step in a FormWizard ran a *different* FormWizard to completion, then the next step in the outer wizard ran yet another FormWizard. Ifeach wizard were a function: `def OuterWizard(): InnerWizard1(); InnerWizard2(); OtherPagesOfOuterWizard()`